# How to get line number in an xml file when it exceeds int.Maxvalue

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am unable to get the linenumber in an xml file that is nearly 300 GB. IXmlLineInfo.LineNumber is an int32 and when it exceeds the int.MaxValue a negative number is returned. It makes no difference if I use an int or a long to store the linenumber -tried both. Xmlreader is able to read to eof.
Using .net 2.0 and newest version also uses an int32.

```
public void ReadLines()
    {
        long readcounter = 0;
        long linenumber = 0;
        fname = "I:\\XML Files\\europe-latest.osm";
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
        settings.XmlResolver = null;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fname, settings);

        IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = ((IXmlLineInfo)reader);
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                linenumber = lineInfo.LineNumber;
                readcounter++;
                if (readcounter % 1000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine(linenumber.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (XmlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Mother of god, a 300GB XML file? Are you sure?

Comment: Perhaps you should stop worrying about getting the line number, and focus on whatever allowed that XML file to get so large.

Comment: @KevinCook Hes saying lineInfo.LineNumber is a int32.

Comment: I'd be tempted to look into using the XmlReaderSettings.LineNumberOffset Property and counting the lines myself in an Int64.

Comment: There's only so much straw you can put on a camel's back.

Comment: As you settings is resolving to XMLTextReader. If you want to parse each node and get its Line in the document, try initializing XMLNodeReader and read the contents with IXmlLineInfo. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo(v=vs.110).aspx ]

Comment: tnw -it's a publicly available file. search for europe-lastest.osm.bz2 and you will find it -dont want to post full url here.

Comment: Mason -customer file, and you might be surprised how common such big files are. all of wikipedia is available in huge xml files. Most government agencies have big ones.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can try:

1) Use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to store actual line number - Check after each operation that the line number is not lesser than it was before, while storing the actual line number in BigInteger. Well, in a very enormous file it can actually overflow and become greater than it was before(after reading, for example, 5 billion line element in few inner increments):

```
var actualLine = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(0);

Int32 lastInt32Line = lineInfo.LineNumber;

// Some Xml reading

Int32 diff = lineInfo.LineNumber - lastLine;

// If an overflow has happened - add overflow
if (diff >= 0)
    actualLine += (new BigInteger(Int32.MaxValue)) * 2 - diff;
else // Everything is normal - add the diff
    actualLine += diff;
```

The real possible problem is that despite the fact that you store the line number correctly the internals of the XmlReader may begin to collapse. In my opinion the `checked` integer arithmetic code should be the default one, not the unchecked as it is now - when the overflow happens then the class is corrupted if it is not explicitly told otherwise.

2) Reorganize your data storage to handle the data in a more fragmented manner.
3) Write your own XmlReader that uses the BigInteger.

Comment: I accept this answer, mainly because I agree there is not much I can try.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating it a bit with [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), it seems the problem is deeply rooted in the internal `XmlTextReaderImpl` class (this should be the actual type of the reader you are using) and internal types it is using:

```
internal struct LineInfo
{
    internal int lineNo;
    internal int linePos;
    // ...
}
```

If you want to approach this with minimal work required, I recommend you get [.NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs), create your own Xml reader by copying `XmlTextReaderImpl` (and all related internal types), replacing all the line number `int`s with `BigInteger`s. If you want to hide the type, you might want to create an interface `IXmlBigLineInfo` or similar, and use it instead of `IXmlLineInfo`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am in .net 2.0. XmlTextReader in 2.0 was not fully XML compliant so I cannot use it. For example, it does not normalize line endings or throw exception if an unreferenced named entity is read. Maybe that was fixed by 4.5 but I doubt it because the XmlReader class is the one MS recommends. Maybe this doesnt apply to XmlTextReaderImpl  and can easily test it.

Comment: XmlTextReaderImpl *is* what you get when you call `XmlReader.Create`. Check `reader.GetType()`.

Comment: Not sure using that class is good long term. Found this as the MSDN XML forum: TextReaderImpl is an internal class which implements the XmlReader "interface". Depending on the reader settings you might get an instance of this class when you call XmlReader.Create. The class is not public because all of its functionality is exposed through the XmlReader class which it inherits from. You should not make any decisions based on the actuall implementation class of the XmlReader as we might choose to change that in the future.

Thanks,
Vitek Karas [MSFT]

Comment: Take a look at what `XmlReader.Create` does, in your case it will *always* return `XmlTextReaderImpl`. It may return something different, in case you pass an existing reader and so on, but that's not your case. I'd say, give it a go - it is going to be less than a day of work.